# What is the maximum duration I can set to gcTime (cacheTime) in React Query?

Tags: reactjs, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I've been using React Query and recently encountered an issue with the gcTime option. I observed that when I set gcTime to a duration of **30 days** (2592000000 milliseconds), it doesn't seem to cache data. Here's the scenario: I navigate from the home page to the cards/id page, it fetches data from the server and caches it. I can verify this in the React Query DevTools. However, when I return to the home page, the cached data is immediately removed. If I go back to cards/id, I see the isLoading flag set to true, even though I've set the gcTime to 30 days in milliseconds.

Strangely, reducing the time to **3 days** resolves the issue. My question is, what is the maximum gcTime I can set? Is there any mention of this in the documentation? I've searched extensively, but I couldn't find any information regarding the maximum duration for gcTime. I only found that the default gcTime is 5 minutes.

```
const useGetCards = (deck_id: string, deck: DeckType | null) => {

  const queryKey = ["cards", deck_id];

  return useQuery({
    queryKey: queryKey,
    queryFn: () => {
      return getCards(deck_id, deck);
    },

    refetchOnWindowFocus: false, // Don't refetch on window focus
    refetchOnReconnect: true, // Refetch on network reconnect
    retry: 0, // no retry on network errorMessage
    gcTime: 2592000000,
  });
};
```

Comment: after doing some online search i founf that  the maximum duration that can be set for gcTime in React Query is determined by the maximum value that can be represented by a 32-bit signed integer in JavaScript, which is 2,147,483,647 milliseconds or approximately 24.85 days.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the code you'll see the `gcTime` utilizes `setTimeout` to do its work.

From MDN, the maximum time you can use there is a 32-bit signed integer, 2,147,483,647 ms (about 24.8 days).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout

Be aware you can also set `Infinity` as a `gcTime` if you want to disable it.  Unless you have a very unusual user situation with their browsers you might as well.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I tried setting gcTime to 2147483647, and it works. However, as soon as I increase it by one millisecond (i.e., 2147483648), it stops working.